# Stuck with "Unknown provider" error when attempting to inject dependency

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, jasmine

I'm trying to unit test an Angular service, using Jamsine, and I'm stuck on how to inject the dependency for that service.

Here is my `app.js` file, trimmed down to the essentials:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("myApp", []);

(function (app) {

    app.factory("taskService", function ($http) {
        return {
            loadTasks: function (callback) {                
            }
        };
    });

    app.controller("AppController", function ($scope, $http, taskService) { 
    });
} (angular.module("myApp")));
```

Here is the Jasmine test, again stripped down to the essentials:

```
describe("taskService tests", function () {

    var svc = {};

    beforeEach(function () {

        angular.module("myApp");    

        // I also tried this, but not luck there either
        // angular.module("myApp", ['taskService']);            

        inject(function (taskService) { // Fails to inject the service.
            svc = taskService;
        });
    });    
});
```

When running the tests, I get the error that `inject` could not resolve the dependency for `taskService`:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector:unpr?p0=taskServiceProvider%20%3C-%20taskService](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector%3aunpr?p0=taskServiceProvider%20%3C-%20taskService)

I'm stuck on what to do here. When running the app itself, the service is injected no problem e.g.

`app.controller("AppController", function ($scope, $http, taskService) {`

but I'm not sure how to manually do the injection in the test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you need to load your module `myApp` using `angular.mocks` not plain angular. It is the same as injecting stuff, you can't use plain angular, you need `angular.mocks`'s `inject()`

So just changing:

```
angular.module("myApp");
```

for:

```
module("myApp");
```

or:

```
angular.mock.module("myApp");
```

Notice that `module()` is just a shorthand of `angular.mock.module()`

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the delay in replying, have been away for Xmas. I'll give your suggestion a try tomorrow, and I'll get back you. Though it's fair to say your answer looks ideal anyway.